# Pycharm can't import pygame - versions not compatible?

Tags: pycharm

I get the error: No module named 'pygame' 
when trying to import pygame in my project in pycharm.

Now I'm trying to troubleshoot, and I wanted to ask whether these versions might be uncompatible. And is there an elegant way I could find out on my own next time?

My Python version is 3.6.0
My pygame version is 1.9.6

Thank you so much!

Comment: `No module named` typically means that the version of Python PyCharm is using isn't the version with e.g. `pygame` installed.

Comment: So are there like Python versions and Pygame versions that are corresponding to each other? bc. there isn't really a "same version" is there? like the most modern version in pygame is 1.9.6 and nothing like 3.6.0

Comment: Apologies. While it is true that certain versions of modules (e.g. `pygame`) work with particular versions of Python  (and may not with other versions), what I was (somewhat carelessly) referring to is that Python installations (each including `pip`) are separate from each other (they don't share modules typically). So if you installed e.g. `pygame` into Python Installation A with `pip` A, that module won't be available to Python Installation B (which has it's own version of `pip` ex. `pip` B).

Comment: Regarding your "compatibility" question, looking at [PyGame on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files) (PyPI is where `pip` pulls modules from) it seems PyGame 1.9.6 supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 - 3.8. So your error has nothing to do with incompatibility (which it wouldn't generally anyway).